# RxJs, subscribe(AnotherBehaviorSubject) vs subscribe((elem) => AnotherSubject.next(elem))

Tags: angular, rxjs

In angular 9 I have a `http` object injected that i call get with and subscribe on the response.
Like the following

```js
somethingElse = new BehaviorSubject<Tweet[]>([]);

http.get<Tweet[]>('/api/bla').subscribe(tweets => somethingElse.next(tweets);
```

Looking ath the API specification for `Observable` one can see `subscribe(observer?: PartialObserver<T>): Subscription;`.

Great, BehaviorSubject is `PartialObserver` (has `next: (value: T) => void;` method)

So why does not the following work?

```js
somethingElse = new BehaviorSubject<Tweet[]>([]);

http.get<Tweet[]>('/api/bla').subscribe(somethingElse);

// NEITHER DOES THIS
// Should be semantically equal to the lambda above?
http.get<Tweet[]>('/api/bla').subscribe(somethingElse.next);
```

In neither of the latter cases the callbacks are invoked. What is the question about?

Comment: Could you please share the code where you're subscribing to the subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A behavior subject is both an observable and an observer. If you use it in a subscribe remember you are also passing in a complete, http calls complete when they emit so this will also complete the behavior subject.

```js
const { of, BehaviorSubject } = rxjs;

const bs$ = new BehaviorSubject('inital');

bs$.subscribe(val => console.log('First sub', val));

of('hello').subscribe(bs$); // of completes and also completes the behavior subject

bs$.subscribe(val => console.log('Sub after complete', val));

bs$.next('we are already complete');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

as for `http.get<Tweet[]>('/api/bla').subscribe(somethingElse.next);` it throws a cannot find length on undefined exception. I would guess that it is a this binding problem where the method is now bound to the new observable and it doesn't have the right this bound.